# Get static values from MPU6050 DMP

Tags: arduino, dmp, mpu

I have a problem in getting clear and not jumping values from MPU9050 DMP. I used Jeff Rowberg's code. The problem is when I use the code all is perfect, YPR is very smooth. But when I use that in my program with delay I have jumping values over time. Depending on the delay, jumping values vary.

I used a delay because I'm reading the serial values by unity and unity needs a little delay on the Arduino side to read the data. Can someone please tell me what the problem is and how I can fix it?

Thanks a lot.

Comment: @dda thanks for correction, but can u also solve my the problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is likely that the fifo buffer is overflowing, leading to incorrect data. This would happen if you put in a delay that lasted for longer than your dmp frequency is. One strategy you could use is to read the data as fast as you can from dmp, but only send data over the serial port every other or every three readings, depending on what kind of delay you need between readings.

If you edit your question with what your dmp frequency is and what your desired serial frequency is I could try to help more.

Comment: thanx for your answer, it was few months that my project was in hold. ill let you know as soon as i started again. thank you in advance